# Schengen visa for Indian studying in USA

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, study, iceland

I want to visit Iceland at the end of my studies in December before I return to India, i.e. I am in the USA on an F-1, want to visit Iceland and then go to India. What would I have to show to convince them that I will return to India?

Comment: "Chances" are a matter of opinion, so off topic.  What you'd have to show is credible evidence of a convincing reason for you to leave the Schengen area (most likely to India because your US studies will have ended).

Comment: While I agree with @phoog that evaluating chances in vacuum is futile, it is still possible to answer that. Note there is also a second part of the question "what to show to convince them".

Comment: Edited the question to remove hold, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Despite having uniform standards, [some Schengen countries are more relaxed in issuing visas](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/visa-statistics-2016/). Iceland is one of them, having the lowest refusal rate for the issuance of uniform visas. As long as you show enough financial resources - it is quite expensive country, even in winter (although way more expensive in summer) - you should be fine.

On the other hand, visiting Iceland in December makes sense only if you're chasing northern lights and enjoy cold weather. There's only five hours of sunlight a day, and most sightseeings are far from Reykyavik (1-3 hour drive). And it is cold and miserable.

Comment: The novelty of the cold and miserable North Atlantic December and its five hours of sunlight might be alone be sufficient reason for an Indian to want to spend a couple of days in Iceland.

Comment: Haha, yep possible. As long as he knows what he's getting into.

Comment: If you get five hours of sunlight in Reykjavík in December you're very lucky!

Comment: Given that I spent an entire year in New England near the Canadian border, I'm completely okay with the harshness of Iceland

Comment: Back to the original question, showing financial resources is not an issue, I will also show my parents as sponsors, but can you give me an example of 'a compelling reason to leave the Schengen area' as @phoog mentioned? (Do note that I am still a student and I may/may not have a job when I apply for a visa) Thanks!

Comment: @JeetKapadia unfortunately, someone in your situation is likely to have some difficulty with the "compelling reason to leave the Schengen area."  The normal factors are a job and a home somewhere else, but as a recent graduate you aren't likely to have these.  You can mention your family ties in India, but having parents or siblings somewhere isn't particularly compelling because people routinely move away from their childhood homes to seek work.  If Iceland really grants visas so readily, though, they may find a simple statement of your plans to be sufficiently credible.